# Best way to bring Desktop CPU from to India?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, electronic-items

I want to bring my CPU which I used in Canada for over 2 years to India with me. What is the best way to do that? Should I check into baggage or carry on or ship it via courier service?

Comment: @Sid: Do you really mean CPU, or computer case? CPU is usually as small as a biscuit. Computer case is usually the size of a briefcase. We can't answer the question if you don't clarify which one you mean. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_case

Answer (score 1):

CPUs are relatively sturdy and quite light, so any way you can carry it is fine. Push it into a sponge or styrofoam pad so that pins do not get bent. I would put it in the carry-on luggage since I would prefer keeping an eye on it, just because it's valuable and small which makes it an easy target for thieves.

[EDIT] With the CPU pins in the sponge, insert it into a anti-static. Most computer parts come in one, so you probably can find one even if you do not have the original.

Couriering it does not seem like a reasonable option because that is quite costly. Even a small package like that shipped to India with tracking or insurance probably costs a significant percentage over what a 2 year old CPU is worth.

Comment: Before wrapping it into a sponge or styrofoam pad, I would put it inside a small electrostatic wrapping to avoid humidity and electric charges generated especially by styrofoam.

Answer (score -2):

The best way would be to ship it via a courier company as you own the computer and it's over 2 years old desktop, I presume it to be heavy, and to carry it as baggage item you would have to pay a lot more.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to transfer a bulky computer to another country for 2 years is simply not to.  Sell it, and take the money with you and buy a new one when you arrive.  Then when you return home, sell it again and do the same when you return home again.

Comment: OP isn't taking a computer, they're only taking the CPU. It'll fit in a top pocket given a bit of foam in an anti-static bag...

Comment: "Desktop CPU" usually means the computer. But the answer stands either way.

Comment: No it doesn't. The CPU is a component inside a computer. Being vague and inaccurate doesn't work on any stack exchange sites.

Comment: Yes, a CPU is a component inside a computer. But many people misuse the term, and when they say "Desktop CPU" in a context like this, they are certainly misusing the term.  The OP _was_ asked to clarify, and in nearly 5 years, still has not provided clarification. And certainly, anybody sophisticated enough to know the difference between an desktop computer, and the CPU component, would be sophisticated enough to realize that a CPU is tiny, and doesn't require special shipping arrangements.